# Power BI: how to select all columns where date is greater in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I'm a newbie I have just started using power bi. I have a table 'users' with a column name 'Date' and some other columns. I want to select the latest record where Date is largest. I don't know how to accomplish this with dax or power query. Really appreciate any sort of help.

Table

```
 ID       AddedDate          Value    
 1       2018/11/01 00:00      105  
 2       2018/11/02 00:00      101  
 3       2018/11/03 00:00      101
```

Output

```
ID       AddedDate          Value
 3       2018/11/03 00:00      101
```

Comment: What do you mean by `select the latest record where Date is largest` ? Please provide some sample data and desired output.

Comment: @Petaflop I have updated the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DAX measure formula (make sure it's a **Measure**, not a calculated column):

```
Latest Value =
VAR 
   Latest_Date = CALCULATE ( MAX ( Users[AddedDate] ), ALL ( Users ) )
RETURN 
   CALCULATE ( SUM ( Users[Value] ), Users[AddedDate] = Latest_Date )
```

Result:

[image]

How it works:

1. First, we find the latest date by looking for a max date in the entire (unfiltered) table, and save it in a variable.
2. Second, we tell DAX to sum only values where date is equal to the latest date we have saved.

Comment: I don't need the grand total. just the row

Comment: You can turn it on or off in your visual.

Comment: You welcome! If it works for you, please mark it as an answer.